# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:3.4.0 in android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

my `build.gradle` is

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and Sync error occurs like below

```
ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:3.4.0.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/3.4.0/gradle-experimental-3.4.0.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/3.4.0/gradle-experimental-3.4.0.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/3.4.0/gradle-experimental-3.4.0.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/3.4.0/gradle-experimental-3.4.0.jar
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/3.4.0/gradle-experimental-3.4.0.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/3.4.0/gradle-experimental-3.4.0.jar
Required by:
    project :app
```

all classpath is doesn't work

how can I fix it?

Comment: Which gradle version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change the "distributionURL" in gradle-wrapper.properties.

In this [page](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) you can see, which gradle version you need.
In your example, I think, this will be the "distributionURL":

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Gradle and the Android plugin run independently from Android Studio, you need to update the build tools separately. Hope this helps... Here is a link to a how to vid. https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEA_enNA829NA829&ei=zd7dXOybJ9Hhgwef9KHAAg&q=update+gradle+in+android+studio&oq=update+gra+in+android+studio&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0i7i30j0i7i5i30.96964.99326..104851...0.0..0.327.3123.2-1j9......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.NTQ5itjULUs#kpvalbx=1

Answer (score 0):

Add google() in your repositories list in build.gradle.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

    }
```