# How to configure android studio to build this project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tensorflow, gradle

I have cloned this project https://github.com/asoehlke/ai-piano-accompanist-app, but could not build it on my android studio.

After running it I get:

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android
>   This version of the NDK may be incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin version 3.0 or older.
>   Please use plugin version 3.1 or newer.

After updating plugin to version 3.4.1 and sync project I get:

> ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:3.4.1.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>     - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/3.4.1/gradle-experimental-3.4.1.pom
>     - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/3.4.1/gradle-experimental-3.4.1.jar
>     - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/3.4.1/gradle-experimental-3.4.1.pom
>     - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental/3.4.1/gradle-experimental-3.4.1.jar
>   Required by:
>       project :

Before update

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.11.0'

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

After update

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:3.4.1'

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

The answers from [Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:3.4.0 in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56169465/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle-experimental3-4-0-in-android-stud) also did not help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56169465/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle-experimental3-4-0-in-android-stud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [android plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#3-4-0)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```

instead of experimental plugin.

Also update the `repositories` blocks:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        //...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    }
}
```

and:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

In `app/build.gradle` you have to change the plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

instead of

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
```

Also you have to adapt the `model` (revome the model keyword)

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
      minSdkVersion XX
      targetSdkVersion 23
      ...
  }
  buildTypes {...}
  ...
}

dependencies {
   //...
}
```

Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build#module-level).

Comment: After applying those I get `Plugin with id 'com.android.model.application' not found.`

Comment: @freir96 Updated the answer. You have to change the plugin in app/build.gradle

Comment: I did but now I get 'Cause: compileSdkVersion is not specified.' despite it is there.

Comment: @freir96 You have to adapt the app/build.gradle according to doc. You have to remove the model block

Comment: I think I did all of that but there is 'Cannot invoke method apiLevel() on null object'.

Comment: @freir96 just remove .apiLevel as described in the doc